# Should the value type be determine for creating a new dictionary when using fromkeys()

Tags: python, dictionary

If I pre-created a dictionary as follows:

```
dict_key = ["[ key 01 ]", "[ key 02 ]", "[ key 03 ]"]
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(dict_key, None)

# my_dict
{
    'key01' : None,
    'key02' : None,
    'key03' : None,
}
```

And at the end of the my code, this dictionary is expected to be returned something as:

```
{
    'key01' : 'value01',
    'key02' : 'value02',
    'key03' : 'value03',
}
```

where the values will be of strings type.

My question here would be for the `my_dict` creation, since the values will be of string type, if I am trying it conform to Python standards, or for someone to review my code, in cases like this - should I change it to `dict.fromkeys(dict_key, '')` or will either work?

Comment: Your question is opinion based, and different people are going to tell you different things. There is no one answer, so just do what you want.

Comment: I don't think standards exist for this, in particular. Python is dynamically typed anyway, and while type hinting is a feature that you could probably use here, the best thing I think you can do is *document input and output formats in the function's docstring and anywhere else they are relevant*.

Comment: Note: `my_dict = dict.fromkeys(dict_key, None)` doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: Is there some reason the keys must be created up front? Simply setting the keys as you compute the values is the usual approach; there is no meaningful performance benefit to be derived from forcing the `dict` to presize.

Answer (score 1):

Add additional:

```
import re
print({re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]','',k):'value0%d'%(list(my_dict.keys()).index(k)+1) for k,v in my_dict.items()})
```

To get desired output:

```
{
    'key01' : 'value01',
    'key02' : 'value02',
    'key03' : 'value03',
}
```

Note: `my_dict = dict.fromkeys(dict_key, None)` doesn't return what you think it does.